# Queueing MySQL record inserts to avoid over-subscription of a related resource ... table locking?

Tags: mysql, transaction, queue

Given a simplified hypothetical of seats in a lifeboat, if I have the following setup with a lifeboats table and a seats table where each record is one occupied seat in the given lifeboat:

```
CREATE TABLE lifeboats (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  total_seats TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO lifeboats (id, total_seats) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO lifeboats (id, total_seats) VALUES (2, 5);

CREATE TABLE seats (
  lifeboat_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO seats (lifeboat_id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO seats (lifeboat_id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO seats (lifeboat_id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO seats (lifeboat_id) VALUES (2);
```

I can find lifeboats with available seats by querying:

```
SELECT 
    l.id, l.total_seats, COUNT(s.lifeboat_id) AS seats_taken
FROM
    lifeboats AS l
        LEFT JOIN
    seats AS s ON s.lifeboat_id = l.id
GROUP BY l.id
HAVING COUNT(s.lifeboat_id) < l.total_seats
```

What is the best way to ensure 2 clients do not grab the last seat in a lifeboat without implementing some coordinating process queue?

My only idea (assuming I'm trying to grab seat in lifeboat 2) is going LOCK TABLE rambo like:

```
LOCK TABLE seats WRITE, lifeboats AS l READ, seats AS s READ;

INSERT INTO seats (lifeboat_id)
SELECT 
    id
FROM
    (SELECT 
        l.id, l.total_seats, COUNT(s.lifeboat_id) AS seats_taken
    FROM
        lifeboats AS l
    LEFT JOIN seats AS s ON s.lifeboat_id = l.id
    WHERE l.id = 2
    GROUP BY l.id
    HAVING COUNT(s.lifeboat_id) < l.total_seats) AS still_available;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

but this is not very elegant, needless to say.

(My environment is MySQL8/InnoDB)

**UPDATE ... Another go:**

I've been called out for giving a bad example. The question is really just:

For a given table, how would you best limit (to X) the number of records inserted with a given value Y?

The process receives the limit X & value Y , you query the existing records where value = Y to see if you are under the limit X or not, and if so you insert the record.

But obviously you risk 2 people grabbing the "last" record unless you ... do something .... but what? (I thought the lifeboat analogy was actually a good one!)

Idea one: Write lock the table before beginning the process. Other processes forced to wait. But this stops everybody ... including others with a different value Y.

Idea/Question 2: If I have a 2nd table t2 with unique set of all the Y values and my select "count of Y" query includes t2 reference + a "FOR UPDATE OF t2", will the write lock placed on the Y row in t2 effectively force processes with value=Y to wait until others have completed the process?

Comment: This looks like a flawed design to me, particularly the `seats` part. Does it truly reflect your _real_ design, or simply a bad analogy?

Comment: A bad analogy, definitely. The real design relates to a fleet of delivery vehicles, a delivery schedule, and committed deliveries. The resource itself (available deliveries for a given time period) fluctuates a lot with vehicle and staffing changes, so it would be difficult to maintain a table with fixed resource amount. Rather I dynamically calculate deliveries available and compare to deliveries committed (shown as seats here).

Comment: If I understand "select for update", I may be able to use a transaction with "select ... for update of lifeboat" even though I never update lifeboat ... ? Then that will force lock/wait of next attempt to look for & insert the same lifeboat ... ?

Comment: I suggest you update your example to be more realistic then, because right now I'm inclined to answer "change your design".

Comment: MariaDB-10.5 has a [WITHOUT OVERLAPS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/application-time-periods/#without-overlaps) index extension that works well with ensuring time base resources don't overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT FOR UPDATE can't lock rows that don't exist, therefore if it is used on table seats, it cannot prevent the insertion of new rows. So if you use that, it has to be done on table lifeboats.

Since customers will be in a hurry to find a lifeboat with available seats, it would be better to let go of the slow count() and add a column occupied_seats in table lifeboats.

This should be updated via a before insert or delete trigger on seats, that does an update on the corresponding row from lifeboat. This update will automatically lock the row, which handles your concurrency issues.

This trigger should raise an error (use SIGNAL sql keyword) if the insert would exceed available seats.

This can be done in a semi lock-free manner by doing

```
UPDATE lifeboats SET occupied_seats = occupied_seats+1 
WHERE id=... AND occupied_seats < available_seats;
```

then testing if that did update one row. That will save one SELECT FOR UPDATE. If it did not update the row, the lifeboat is full, throw an error. If it did, this also locks the row, so COMMIT quickly.

Comment: I like this idea & am inclined to accept, but wondering how you feel about my idea of "select .. for update of lifeboats" idea if I do not use the occupied seats column / do not actually update lifeboats. Does it still lock the process for the given lifeboat?

Comment: Yes it will lock row, more precisely it will lock out other SELECTs FOR UPDATE of the same row, which is what you need. However you will have to hold the lock for a longer time (counting the rows) and it does not protect against modifying the tables via some other means, like manually, which a trigger would also handle.